# How to get all properties (including undefined) using reflection in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, reflection, ecmascript-6

I have:

```
let requiredSymbobl = Symbol('required');
let function required() { return Reflect.metadata(requiredSymbol, null); }

class Person {
  @required();
  name: string;
}


let p = new Person(); //In reality comes from POST data

//Validate every key with required meta data.
for(let key in p) {
  if(typeof Reflect.getMetadata(requiredSymbol, p, key) !== 'undefined') {
    //Validate 
  }
}
```

The problem is if the client doesn't POST an object with 'name'property defined, it won't be iterated in the loop. Is there a way to use static reflection here to check all keys even if they aren't defined?

Comment: Please don't use excessive formatting.

Comment: I should clarify, not looking for a solution whereby a value is defined within the class declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If properties don't exist on the object, they cannot be iterated. In fact, they are not properties.

The properties that are supposed to exist on the object should be added to the list:

```
for (const key of Array.from(new Set([...Object.keys(p), 'name'])))
  ...
```

Or for TypeScript with downlevel iterators enabled:

```
for (const key of new Set([...Object.keys(p), 'name']))
  ...
```

Since `Object.keys` returns own enumerable keys, this may not work as expected on complex objects that rely on prototype chain but will work on plain object.

Another way is to make class accept all properties it needs in constructor. The class can also be responsible for its validation:

```
class Person {
  @required();
  name: string;

  constructor(plainObj) {
    this.name = plainObj.name;
    ...
  }

  validate() {
    // only enumerable instance props
    for (const key of Object.keys(this))
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: is 'required' meant to be 'email' in your first two code snippets?

Comment: I changed it to `name` as original code shows for clarity.

Comment: whoops sorry yip that's what I meant -haha. Cheers